# Adding columns for mean and sd of rows in R

Tags: r

I have following data frame:

```
> ddf
  aa bb cc dd
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
3  9 10 11 12
> 
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(aa = c(1L, 5L, 9L), bb = c(2L, 6L, 10L), cc = c(3L, 
7L, 11L), dd = c(4L, 8L, 12L)), .Names = c("aa", "bb", "cc", 
"dd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
>
```

I want to add mean and sd columns (mean and sd for each row) but following does not work:

```
ddf$mean = mean(ddf[,1:4])
Warning message:
In mean.default(ddf[, 1:4]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> ddf$sd = sd(ddf[,1:4])
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> 
> ddf
  aa bb cc dd mean
1  1  2  3  4   NA
2  5  6  7  8   NA
3  9 10 11 12   NA
```

How can I add columns for mean and sd (for each row)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write a function for this.  That way you can add to it later if need be, and you don't need to write `na.rm = TRUE` multiple times.

```
foo <- function(x, digits = 3L, ...) {
    x <- c(x, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
    res <- c(mean = mean(x, ...), sd = sd(x, ...),
             median = median(x, ...), max = max(x, ...))
    round(res, digits)
}
cbind(ddf, t(apply(ddf, 1, foo, na.rm = TRUE)))
#   aa bb cc dd mean    sd median max
# 1  1  2  3  4  2.5 1.291    2.5   4
# 2  5  6  7  8  6.5 1.291    6.5   8
# 3  9 10 11 12 10.5 1.291   10.5  12
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get mean for each column, you can use rowMeans(). For SD, I used apply() here.

```
ddf$Rmean <- rowMeans(ddf)
ddf$SD <- apply(ddf[1:4], 1, sd)

#  aa bb cc dd Rmean       SD
#1  1  2  3  4   2.5 1.290994
#2  5  6  7  8   6.5 1.290994
#3  9 10 11 12  10.5 1.290994
```

Comment: No need for `function(x) sd(x)` - just `sd` will do.

Comment: @Richard I initially wrote `apply(ddf, 1, sd)`. But, I realised that the SD values were not right. If I run the two lines from my answer, SD is 1.118034. So, I changed `ddf` to `def[1:4]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `matrixStats` which already has`rowMedians`, `rowSds`, `rowMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)

 m1 <- as.matrix(ddf)
 cbind(ddf, 
       mean=rowMeans(m1),sd=rowSds(m1), median=rowMedians(m1), max=rowMaxs(m1)) 
 #  aa bb cc dd mean       sd median max
 #1  1  2  3  4  2.5 1.290994    2.5   4
 #2  5  6  7  8  6.5 1.290994    6.5   8
 #3  9 10 11 12 10.5 1.290994   10.5  12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rowmeansmean<- rowMeans(ddf, na.rm = TRUE) #will get you your row means. 

ddfwithmean<- cbind(ddf, rowmeansmean) # adds means to existing dataframe
```

You then need to do the same with SD, this can be done with `apply()`  but also see  Jazzuro's answer for details